# Dropdown Button made from UITableView not overlapping buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I implemented a dropdown button using a TableView such that when a user clicks the button a dropdown list pops up at the bottom of the button. Thus far this feature works fine. However, when I add another button at the bottom of the first button and I click the dropdown, the tableView doesn't overlap the button at the Bottom. Instead of appearing on-top it appears underneath.

My question is how do I get the tableView to appear on-top of the 2nd button when the dropdown button is clicked.. I have inserted my code below.

```js
#
import < UIKit / UIKit.h >

@interface ViewController: UIViewController < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate >

@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton * categoriesBtn;
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * categoriesTable;

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray * data; 
 -(IBAction) categoriesButton: (id) sender;
 -(IBAction) submit: (id) sender;

@end
```

```js
@implementation ViewController

  -(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.categoriesBtn setTitle: @ "+ Categories" forState: UIControlStateNormal ];
    self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @ "Value1", @ "Value2", @ "Value3", @ "Value4", @ "Value5", nil ];
    self.categoriesTable.delegate = self;
    self.categoriesTable.dataSource = self;
    self.categoriesTable.hidden = YES;

  }

  -(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView * ) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section {

    return [self.data count];

  }

  -(UITableViewCell * ) tableView: (UITableView * ) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath * ) indexPath {

    static NSString * simpleTableIdentifier = @ "SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
  }

  -(IBAction) categoriesButton: (id) sender {
    if (self.categoriesTable.hidden == YES) {
      self.categoriesTable.hidden = NO;
    } else
      self.categoriesTable.hidden = YES;
  }


  -(void) tableView: (UITableView * ) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath * ) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.categoriesTable cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    [self.categoriesBtn setTitle: cell.textLabel.text forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    self.categoriesTable.hidden = YES;

  }

  -(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  }

@end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many `UITableView` do you have? And i can't find where is your button on each cell.

Comment: I only have one UITableView for now however I want to implement more than one once I get this part working. Im not sure I understand the question about the button on a cell.

Comment: What is your dropdown list? `the button on a cell` i mean i can't see and button on your cell ;)

Comment: my drop downlist is the array defined in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: No, i mean what view displays your array

Comment: UITableViewCell * cell = [self.categoriesTable cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

Comment: the categorisTable displays the array

Comment: Can you show your controller xib?

Comment: Im a using storyboards not xib files

Comment: Ok i mean your controller in storyboards

Comment: By controller do u mean my ViewController.m class file or do you mean something else because I don't think I understand

Comment: I have added an answer, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `categoriesTable` overlap `queryTypeButton`, you should change you order of `ViewController`'s subviews like below image. With this order, `categoriesButton` is below buttons so when it's displayed on screen, it will be on the top of screen (view tree).

[image]

Or each time you click `categoriesButton` you should bring your `categoriesTable` to front. If you do it, your `categoriesTable` will overlap all of your buttons when it appears. Change your `categoriesButton` method like this

```
-(IBAction)categoriesButton: (id) sender {
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.categoriesTable];

  if (self.categoriesTable.hidden == YES) {
    self.categoriesTable.hidden = NO;
  } else
    self.categoriesTable.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked. Do you mind explaining why changing the order works.

Comment: @kudzi i have updated my answer with some explaining. If you don't understand, let me know ;)

Comment: Thats the simplest and best explanation thank you. Its clear and I understand it.

Comment: Welcome my friend @kudzi ;)