# UINavigationController Subview not Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am having a navigation controller and a view, which i attached to the subview of navigation controller, i used the below code to hide the navigation bar while swiping up

```
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview: categoryView];
    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

it is hiding to the top while swiping the tableview up, but i want that subview should move up along with the navigation controller and it should fit at the top, while swiping down navigation bar should come down along with the subview.

I tried this

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview: categoryView];`

In this both navigationBar and the subview is hiding to the top. I guess some simple solutions will be there for this, I searched a lot but didn't find a perfect one. I tried some libraries too, those are not fitting for iPhone X and having some issues in iOS 11.

Update:  adding images for the issue [before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8cJU.png)
and 
[after scrolling the tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdD3y.png)

Comment: You need something like http://www.iostute.com/2015/09/how-to-implement-parallax-scrolling.html

Comment: No, not like that, i need like TLYShyNavBar library, it has an extension view. I tried it but it is not working for all the screens. https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar @JonSnow

Comment: currently i am using AMScrollingNavbar objc files, but it is not fitting fine for iPhone X, thats why i am trying manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

You can add subview to your view with constraints to safe area.

F.e. programmatically:

```
self.headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    UILayoutGuide *guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
                                              [self.headerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:0],
                                              [self.headerView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor constant:64],
                                              [self.headerView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor constant:0],
                                              [self.headerView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:0]
                                              ]];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
                                              [self.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.headerView.bottomAnchor constant:0],
                                              [self.tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor constant:0],
                                              [self.tableView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:0],
                                              [self.tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor constant:0]
                                              ]];


}
```

To show/hide navbar on scroll you may use:

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated: YES];
} else {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated: YES];
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:[CATransaction animationDuration]
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

[image]

Updated example: https://github.com/josshad/HideNavBarOnScrollExample

Comment: i need to show / attach one more view below the navigation bar and that should also scroll with the navigation bar and hide while swiping up, when swiping down the navigation bar should come down. @Josshad

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. You have to look around the safe area. Updated answer and example.

Comment: Wow, its simple and nice +1, Is this possible by doing programmatically ? because i am having https://github.com/hightower/HTHorizontalSelectionList as the subview.

Comment: You can read article where described adding constraints to safe area programmatically (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/).
Or you can use library with IB support: https://github.com/josshad/EHHorizontalSelectionView

Comment: Thank you @Josshad I will try all the suggestion you mentioned. I gave the bounty to you :)

Answer (score 0):

write this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47081269/8125593

Comment: i think you want to hide navigation controller@R.Mohan

Comment: yes, while scrolling the tableview up, it should hide. When i scrolling the tableview down, it should be visible.

Comment: prefer this link i think it should  be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
  } else {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
  }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: its not working, i updated my question with images, check it. if you get anyother solution, kindly suggest me. thank you.

Comment: Did you check if ```[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];``` or ```[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];``` is called ?

Comment: yes, i checked it, i am getting the same as the code in my question does, i want that yellow color subview to move along with the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom View as a header View instead of using navigation bar (make the navigation bar hidden). Now give constraints to your header View (height constraint). When you will scroll your table view, Method `-scrollViewDidScroll` will be called. check the scrollview's content offset, if its greater than 0.

`headerView.heightconstraint -= scrollViewContentoffset.y;`

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEpZB.jpg)
[after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkwfw.jpg)

Comment: I am using the CAPS page menu (your category view). And bottom constraint between headerView and Menu View is 0.

Comment: i too tried capspagemenu previously but faced memory and performance problems, thats why now using SwipeView with HTHorizontalSelectionList. Ok, i will try the above suggestion and let you know the result @bhanu matta, thank you.

Comment: headerView.heightconstraint is this possible, i am trying it now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this awesome tutorial by Brian Voong on LetsBuildThatApp Youtube channel. He explains the same feature which you are referring to with awful amount of details.

[NavBarView Sliding Feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgRbj4YeG9I&index=11&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i want to know where i am referring with awful amount of details. Either in my question or in comments.

Comment: I said that the instructor in that tutorial will mention plenty details in his tutorial video. I did not mention you.

Comment: Oh ok, will check it.